# How to calculate sum of an object each 2 its value in js

Tags: object, sum, reduce

i have an object like this, how can i calculate total value of code and codePrev :

```
{
    "code01Prev": 3756743628,
    "code01": 10346000,
    "code02Prev": 0,
    "code02": 0,
    "code10Prev": 3756743628,
    "code10": 10346000,
    "code11Prev": 0,
    "code11": 0,
    "code20Prev": 3756743628,
    "code20": 10346000
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going with plain vanilla. The code is a little bit imperative (not explaining what but how). If possible it would be good to consider changing data structure.

```js
data = {
    code01Prev: 3756743628,
    code01: 10346000,
    code02Prev: 0,
    code02: 0,
    code10Prev: 3756743628,
    code10: 10346000,
    code11Prev: 0,
    code11: 0,
    code20Prev: 3756743628,
    code20: 10346000
}

initialTotals = {
  code: 0,
  codePrev: 0}
    
dataKeyValues = Object.entries(data)    

totals = dataKeyValues.reduce(
  (totalAccumulated, [key, value]) => {
    if (key.endsWith('Prev')){
      return {
        ...totalAccumulated,
        codePrev: totalAccumulated.codePrev + value}}
    return {
      ...totalAccumulated,
      code: totalAccumulated.code + value}},
  initialTotals)

console.log(totals)

// totals:
// {
//   "code": 31038000,
//   "codePrev": 11270230884
// }
```